# faster append of sum values to dataframe using iterator as both column and index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was wondering a fastest and cleanest way to write code for appending my values of summation to a new empty dataframe.

I have tried using .sum() and sum() as well as pandas series and apply().

But I wish to confirm if I am at the optimum of my thinking of writing cleanest and fastest code here. I would prefer fastest if both cannot be achieved at same time.

Cleaner meaning a much readable or reusable code here.
This is a messy code for me. It works as I desire, but I want a solution faster than this.

```
df_year = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1960,2018,1):    
    df_year[str(i)] = pd.Series(sum(df_indicator[str(i)]))
```

The sample data for all three countries is as follows:

df_indicator

```
    Country Name    Country Code    Indicator Name  Indicator Code  1960    1961    1962    1963    1964    1965    1966    1967
33  Canada  CAN Population, total   SP.POP.TOTL 17909009.0  18271000.0  18614000.0  18964000.0  19325000.0  19678000.0  20048000.0  20412000.0
152 Mexico  MEX Population, total   SP.POP.TOTL 38174112.0  39394126.0  40649588.0  41939880.0  43264272.0  44623043.0  46011038.0  47429812.0
249 United States   USA Population, total   SP.POP.TOTL 180671000.0 183691000.0 186538000.0 189242000.0 191889000.0 194303000.0 196560000.0 198712000.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [2]: df = DataFrame({'Country': ['US', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Belize'], '1960': range(4), '1961': range(10, 14)})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  Country  1960  1961
0      US     0    10
1  Canada     1    11
2  Mexico     2    12
3  Belize     3    13

In [4]: res = df[df['Country'].isin(['US', 'Canada'])].sum()

In [5]: res
Out[5]:
Country    USCanada
1960              1
1961             21
dtype: object
```

Obviously you can manipulate resulting series to suit your needs:

```
In [6]: df_year = DataFrame(df[df['Country'].isin(['US', 'Canada'])].sum()).transpose().drop(['Country'], inplace=True, axis=1)

In [7]: df_year.drop(['Country'], inplace=True, axis=1)

In [8]: df_year
Out[8]:
  1960 1961
0    1   21
```

Comment: Yes. But my code works and gives me the output which I desire. But my concern is about the data that will pile up as years go on. Hence I want a solution which makes this operation faster than what I have currently written

Comment: a) This solution is much faster because it relies on Pandas inherent dataframe efficiencies. You can test this against your code with `%timeit`.
b) The other issue with your code is that it will break if `df_indicator` has less columns than what you're putting in the range of your loop (e.g. it goes only to 2005 and your range goes to 2018). This means with every year you will need to change the code. The solution above is agnostic to the number of columns in the input dataframe.

Comment: I updated the answer to give the output you desire, according to your code. Unless of course I don't understand your intended output...

Comment: I think you are right. I am gonna take this as answer, but can you please check once again the code and question if it is clear now? I have edited it to suite better

Comment: Looks like you removed the country filtering, which I thought was the whole point of your question. The other thing about the code which is unclear to me is making a series out of a single number `pd.Series(sum(df_indicator[str(i)]))`. If I understand correctly, with every loop iteration the code is summing up a column (for example '2006') into a single number, and then making it into a series. I don't quite understand what it's trying to do.

Comment: Yes very right. The i generates a column in empty dataframedf_year because the i is the labelled column of df_indicator whose values I have to sum up. Thus in the end the df_year will be left with columns from 1960 to 2017 and only 1 row displaying the sum of values of numbers in those years which lie in df_indicator dataframe. Is this clear now? hope this helps? :(

Comment: I understand what the code is doing, I just don't understand why. Anyway I hope the solution helps.

Comment: This is a small part of larger code that I am writing for building a data pipeline for my project by focusing on only these three countries for now :) Thanks again